# How to SUM cells value skip blank cells in iWork Numbers?

Tags: apple-numbers

When the range of cells contain blank cell, the sum function always give a 0,

```
column
2
3
blank
blank
4
=sum(A2:A6)
```

I expected the SUM give 9, but it is zero. The formula `=SUMIF(A2:A6,"<>")` not work, may be it work for excel, but not in Numbers

Comment: I find the newest version already fixed this bug

Answer (score 0):

Turn Blank into "0" instead of leaving it blank.
Use IsNull(Column, 0)